# Why cant i push element onto sub array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-push, indexed

I'm trying to understand something about arrays in for each loops that might be obvious to many.

When i loop through my multi-dimensional array, i attempt to find sub arrays with no third element. If they have no third element, i want to add a third element to that sub array with a specific value.

```
$testArray = array (
    array("Green", "Yellow", "Blue"),
    array("Brown", "Silver"),
    array("Orange", "Pink", "Black"),
);
```

When i use the foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $testArray as $key => $array ) {
    if (count($array) == '2') {
        $array[] = "None";
    };
}
```

No errors are thrown but nothing happens. When i use the for each loop:

```
foreach ( $testArray as $key => $array ) {
    if (count($array) == '2') {
        $testArray[$key][] = "None";
    };
}
```

It works as expected.

Sorry for the long preamble, my questions is:

Why aren't these two foreach loops doing the same thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here lies in the fact that foreach iterates over iterables and sets the iteration variable by value. This means that the `$array` which you are dealing with in the `foreach` is not the same value of the `$testArray`.

To rememdy this (and avoid introducing an `$index` variable to mutate an item in the array), you will need to tell foreach to [pass the value by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). References are PHP's answer to C-style pointers. If a variable references another, both variables point to the same value, so a modification to the contents of one is in effect a modification to the other. In your `foreach`, you can use `&$array` to have the loop pass you the items of `$testArray` by reference instead of by value:

```
foreach ( $testArray as $key => &$array ) {
    if (count($array) == '2') {
        $array[] = "None";
    }
}
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/avGSAj06))

This aligns with PHP's references, where one variable can be made to reference another like so:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = &$a;
$b[] = 4;

print_r($a); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/QU0jqFvj))

You experience a similar phenomenon with functions:

```
function byValue($a) {
    $a[] = 4;
}

function byRef(&$a) {
    $a[] = 5;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3);

byValue($a);
print_r($a); // 1, 2, 3

byRef($a);
print_r($a); // 1, 2, 3, 5
```

([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/55E3R8AQ))

The [references section of the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) has some examples about this syntax of `foreach`. Also note [this (somewhat) related, but interesting read on `foreach` and references](http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html).

---

Also, on an unrelated note if you weren't aware: you don't need a semicolon after closing a block with `}` in PHP unless you're doing something like assigning a closure to a variable:

```
$someFunc = function($a) { return $a; }; //need one here

if(1 + 2 == 4) {
   echo "I just broke math";
} // but you don't need one here
```

Comment: Thanks Php, very thorough answer, and very helpful in understanding how references work. Thanks also to everyone who answered.

Comment: Also, good comment on the semicolon, as a beginner I find basic tips like that invaluable! Cheers - jreidko

Answer (score 4):

Because you need to access $testArray entries "**by reference**"

```
foreach ( $testArray as &$array ) {
    if (count($array) == 2) {
        $array[] = "None";
    };
}
unset($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` loops do not pass the elements by reference. To get the first array to do what you want, it would have to be:

```
foreach ( $testArray as $key => &$array ) {
    if (count($array) == '2') {
        $array[] = "None";
    };
}
```